# No utility classes were detected in my source files even though i included them

Tags: tailwind-css

my utility classes are not getting detected for some reason, i tried everything and wasted 4 hours already, so for a better understanding of the problem i'll link a photo of my project structure and show the full error that is driving me crazy,
[FULL DESCRIPTION OF STRUCTURE AND ERROR MUST SEE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpP1z.png)
I used `npx tailwindcss init` to see my tailwind.config.js file to see the contents and it turned out to be empty even though i followed the necessary steps and also included the base utilities in the src folder which inludes these `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`

steps i took:-

1) `npm init -y`

2) `npm install tailwindcss`

3) `npm run build-css`

4) `npm init -y`

Comment: Can you share more about the specific error message you are encountering?.
And next share your project structure in order to give me a better understanding of how everything is set up.

Comment: @DavidTeo You can see the project structure from looking at the image i linked and for more context the src folder holds the @tailwind base ,components and utilities,what i want to see the output of the tailwind css code i inserted in the index.html to be visible when i run it , THIS IS THE ERROR :-
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to add file globs that cover files that contain Tailwind classes, as per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration). In your particular case, I'll assume that you have some Tailwind classes in the `public/index.html`, in which case, consider adding the file path to your `content` array:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    'public/index.html',
```

This will tell Tailwind to scan this file for Tailwind classes and build the appropriate CSS rules into the output CSS file.

Comment: it only worked for 1 iteration meaning that if i dont rebuild the entire project the changes wont be into effect so in this specific case i turned the background yellow and it worked after building it then i turned it red and saved it but it wont change, it does so if i rebuild the project using these comands : 1)npm run build-css 2) live-server public

Comment: Consider checking you have `--watch` if you are using the `tailwindcss` command in your  `build-css` npm script.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours of investigating, the only was to use at least one utility classes in any of my source files. It could be as easy as `class="text-red-500"`. This will get rid of this warning.